# Replacing groups within h5py File keeps growing the size

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, h5py

I have some data frames that I need to store in an HDF5 file, both individually as well as concatenated. I am trying to use groups to preserve the individual data frames. The data frames are saved using:

```
df1.to_hdf(filename, key="S1", mode="a", complevel=9)
df2.to_hdf(filename, key="S2", mode="a", complevel=9)
...
```

and then the concatenated data frame is saved as:

```
df_concatenated = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_concatenated.to_hdf(filename, key="key", mode="a", complevel=9)
```

The functionality works and re-loading the data frames confirms that both individual and concatenated data frames are preserved correctly. However, the file size keeps growing every time I run `to_hdf`. The keys in the file remain the same after every write, though:

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File(filename, mode='r')
f.keys()
```

shows `["S1", "S2", "key"]` as expected.

I thought the issue was being caused by some dangling data, so I added code to delete previously existing data, if applicable:

```
try:
    with h5py.File(filename, mode='a') as f:
        del f[key]
except (KeyError, TypeError, FileNotFoundError):
    pass
```

But the file size keeps growing, almost doubling every time I overwrite portion of the file (one key and the composite "key").

How can I keep the file size constant for same data? That is, if I use `to_hdf` to overwrite the data with identical data frame, how can I ensure that the file size should remain the same?

Comment: HDF5 does not recover allocated space from deleted data. It will reuse space if you add data. Solution is to run the `repack` utility (from HDF Group) or `ptrepack` delivered with PyTables package.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @kcw78 for your explanation and a possible solution. I am not in control of the environment where this code may run, so I cannot reliably invoke the utilities.

Here is the solution I am using right now. Not ideal, but it works.

```
with h5py.File(filename, mode='r') as f:
    all_keys = list(f.keys())

...

df_dict = {}
for k in all_keys:
    if k != "key":
        df_dict[k] = pd.read_hdf(filename, key=k)

...

# Overwrite file here
df_concatenated.to_hdf(filename, key="key", mode="w", complevel=9)

...
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    v.to_hdf(filename, key=k, mode="a", complevel=9)
```

Basically I just load all the data frames in memory and, when writing the combined data frame back, I use `mode="w"`. This overwrites the previous file, resulting in an automatic "repack". Then I write back the other keys.

In my case the data frames are not excessively large so the one-time loading of all data frames in memory is feasible. The resulting file size is now exactly what it should be.